# Brightness problem after upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10 on ASUS Slimbook X401U

Tags: brightness, asus, 13.10

I have upgraded to 13.10 recently. Previously the brightness worked after I added this to `/etc/rc.local`.

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

But after I upgraded to 13.10, this code is not working. I use an ASUS Slimbook X401U.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your brightness using xrandr like in this example.

```
sudo xrandr --output LVDS --brightness 0.3
```

Also you can try to switch to fglrx drivers and than switch back to the open source drivers.
Switching between drivers in ubuntu unity is very easy. 
Just follow those steps in the UI:
System Settings, Software and Updates, Additional Drivers.

Comment: The xrandr command are making my colors to look like sh***t so I decided to try it in another way. Please read my next answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a sample script based on bash dialog, in order to change my laptop brightness until they fix that in 13.10.

[Here is the source on github](https://github.com/kjpopov/Ubuntu-Useful-Scripts/blob/master/choose_brightness)

You can edit it to add more values, and also you can change line 33 to make it work for your video adapter.

I am using Asus X55U laptop with Radeon HD 6290

Make sure you execute the script with root privileges.

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers on different questions. It just creates more work for the moderators. If the questions are so similar that the same answer works on each, then the later of the two is likely a duplicate and should be flagged as such.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an intel video card do:

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

Add the following in the empty file then log out and log in again or reboot. That should fix your problem.

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "card0"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"

EndSection
```

Comment: I use AMD Radeon Graphics Card, not Intel.