# Brightness at 100% since updating from Kubuntu 13.04 to 13.10

Tags: ati, kubuntu, laptop, brightness

since I've updated to Kubuntu 13.10 my brightness level is at 100%. I already googled around and tried different tips, but none of them worked.

I've edited /etc/default/grub to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
acpi_osi="linux"
```

Also I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the proprietary ATI Fire GL driver, but I think I've completely messed up the system by doing so, because now the /sys/class/backlight/ directory is empty which wasn't before. Unfortunately I don't know how to get it back. Also since then the settings for adjusting the screen brightness in the power management are gone.

I have a Toshiba Satellite Pro notebook. Naturally the FN keys for adjusting the brightness don't work either, but worked fine on 13.04.

I'd be glad if someone could help me there since my eyes can't handle this brightness. ;)

Edit:
I've solved this by following the steps in 2.1 of https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI for un-installing the installed driver. In short I did the following:

```
sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.BAK

sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx-amdcccle

sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates
```

After the reboot my screen went black. First I was afraid I messed something up, but then I tried using the FN-keys to bring up the brightness and they worked!

Then I followed the rest of the steps in 2.1 and installed the drivers again, but after the restart, the brightness was stuck at 100% again, so I did the un-installation steps again and the brightness control works again.

I'm just not sure if I should try installing the Catalyst drivers directly from the AMD's page or not. But for the moment everything seems to be ok, except of the fact that I'm running with the default drivers.

Comment: As a workaround try [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/364531/121304):

`sudo xrandr --output LVDS --brightness 0.3`

Comment: Thank you @bfootdav, this works. But it seems to make everything blurry.... Is there any other way to control the brightness?

Comment: I'm in the exact same boat as you and I haven't found anything. My Toshiba with ATI card was working perfectly with 13.04 but now with 13.10 all sorts of things are broken including setting the brightness. You're supposed to be able to use `xbacklight` (it works on the hardware level as opposed to the software level of xrandr) but I (and many others, it appears) have been unable to get it to do anything. It's frustrating.